# Inconvenientes con Store Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando un *SP* para realizar una búsqueda específica con parametros, pero me trae el siguiente error. ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure spPantallaTasa, Line 6
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@aseguradora".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure spPantallaTasa, Line 10
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@aseguradora".

SQL:

```
CREATE PROC spPantallaTasa
@asegradora VARCHAR(20)
AS
    IF (@aseguradora = 'Caracas')
        BEGIN
            Select Año, TipoCotizacion, Estatus, TipoVehiculo, SubTipoVehiculo, ClaseCompañia, Zona 
            FROM [dbo].[RelacionClaseTasa], [dbo].[MPF_Tasas]
            WHERE Aseguradora = @aseguradora
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT 1

        END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los nombres de la variable no están iguales... en el parámetro del job te faltó la U: @asegRadora y @aseguradora

Answer (score 0):

el problema esta en que la variable que declaraste se llama @asegradora y mas abajo la llamas por @aseguradora en ves de @asegradora.
Saludos